# Deploying adaptive multi-user Dask cluster on Kubernetes

Tags: python, dask-distributed, dask-kubernetes

What is the proper way to deploy an adaptive multi-user Dask cluster on Kubernetes?

I need a centralized cluster of machines multiple people can use for their work, so that it can add more machines or remove them (preferably, to 0 workers).

Answer (score 3):

Given that you have a requirement for multiple people to share a cluster of machines that you manage I recommend you check out [Dask Gateway](https://gateway.dask.org/).

A Dask cluster is only designed to be used by one person at a time. You can create clusters using the [Dask Helm Chart](https://helm.dask.org/) or with [dask-kubernetes](https://kubernetes.dask.org/en/latest/), but each of these methods creates a single cluster for use by one person.

Dask Gateway provides a secure, multi-tenant server for managing Dask clusters.

To get started on Kubernetes you need to create a Helm configuration file (`config.yaml`) with a gateway proxy token.

```
gateway:
  proxyToken: "<RANDOM TOKEN>"
```

*Hint: You can generate a suitable token with `openssl rand -hex 32`.*

Then install the chart.

```
helm repo add dask-gateway https://dask.org/dask-gateway-helm-repo/
helm repo update
helm install --values config.yaml my-release dask-gateway/dask-gateway
```

[Dask Gateway Kubernetes Documentation](https://gateway.dask.org/install-kube.html)